# Checking equality between two objects on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a set of cars(So a car model). Each car has availability dates, on which it is available (so another model "availability"). 
I have another model called 'appointment', on this day I can now select a few cars, but this day must also correspond to a day on which all the cars selected are available. So, what I though of was counting my cars, one one hand. On the other hand see all the available dates for the first car and for each day available see if other cars are also available on this day. In fact the number of my cars must correspond to the count of available dates. I hope I've been clear. Anyway this was was I though of:

my controller

```
def available_date
  @cars = 0
  @available = 0
  @cars = @appointment.cars.count

  @appointment.cars.first.availability.each do |d|
    @available = Availability.find_all_by_day(d.day)
    if @available.count == @cars
      @appointment.day = @available
    end
  @available.save
  end
end
```

This doesn't seem to work, also I was thinking, if there are more than one availability it would not work also.

Answer (score 0):

If `@available.count == @cars` then you want to set `@appointment.day = d.day`

If you then `break` you'll exit the each loop and have the earliest possible appointment date (assuming availability is ordered by day ascending)

If @appointment.day is nil at the end of the each loop, there were no dates shared by all cars.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried to do it, but it did not work. Thank you all the same

Comment: Can  you remove the available save?  Also, what does the code look like where you're calling this method?